# removing an element from array not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying an element from an array using the id of the element yet not successful.

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state = {

     arr : [<Input id="1" />,<Input id="2" />,<Input id="3" />,<Input id="4" />],
     id: 5 

   }
 }

   addToArray(){
    let id = this.state.id
    let arr = this.state.arr
    let tmp = <Input id={id} />
    id = id + 1
    arr.push(tmp)
    this.setState({arr,id})

  }


   removeFromArray(){

     let idx = prompt("Enter index")

     let data = [...this.state.arr]
     let arr_two = []

      arr_two = data.filter(function( element ) {
           return (element.props.id !== idx );
        }); 

      this.setState({arr: arr_two})


}

render(

   return(){

    <Button onClick={() => {this. addToArray()}}>add to array</Button>
   <Button onClick={() => {this.removeFromArray()}}>remove from array</Button>

}
)
```

no matter what value the user enters, only the last element is being removed. Let say the user inputs 2, the element with the id 4 is gets removed instead of 2 although it exists in the array. How should I modify to resolve the issue

Comment: Please attempt to format your code properly. People who would love to help you will turn away since it's hard to read your code.

Comment: Can you provide some more code? Like how you render these `<Input >`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of syntax errors in your original code, and you're not following best practices (e.g. if you're referencing `state` when using `setState`, use the callback because `setState` is asynchronous), but I think the primary issue you were having is that you're comparing strings to numbers.

I refactored your code to use more current methods (i.e. ES6) and added `parseInt` to convert the input from `window.prompt` into a `number` that can be compared to your `<Input />` component’s `id` prop. I also switched the explicit `<Input />` declarations to use a numeric input, rather than a string.

Hit run and you'll see that it works as-is.

```js
const Input = ({ id }) => <div>{id}</div>

class Foo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    arr: [
      <Input id={1} />,
      <Input id={2} />,
      <Input id={3} />,
      <Input id={4} />,
    ],
    id: 5,
  }

  addToArray = () => {
    const arr = [...this.state.arr, <Input id={this.state.id} />]
    this.setState(prevState => ({ arr, id: prevState.id + 1 }))
  }

  removeFromArray = () => {
    const id = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter index"))

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      arr: prevState.arr.filter(element => element.props.id !== id),
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.addToArray}>Add to array</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.removeFromArray}>Remove from array</button>
        </div>
        Array: {this.state.arr}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```